# FilamentPHP Select input editing

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Heyya,

I am working on Select

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('roles')->options(function (){
                            $roles = Role::pluck('name');
                            $filtered_roles = $roles->filter(fn($role)=>$role!='super_admin');
                            return $filtered_roles;
                        })->searchable()->preload()->multiple()
```

Works great. However on the edit page it doesnt show already defined roles for specific user. Each time it show select one of the roles

I expect it would show me currently selected roles on edit

Comment: Are you using any package to manage roles ? Or Just a columns in the users table with ```json``` or ```array``` data type

Answer (score 0):

Use `fill()` in `mount()`

```
function mount()
{
  $this->form->fill([
    'roles' => $user->roles->pluck('name')
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I was using Filament Shield plugin for permission & roles. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is a solution i manage to find myself.

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('roles')
                            ->relationship('roles', 'name', fn(Builder $query) => $query->whereNot('name', 'super_admin'))
                            ->searchable()
                            ->preload()
                            ->multiple()
```

I hope it will be useful for you guys who suffer same situation.